# SQL Update only 1000 rows out of a million

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with five columns and just over 1000 rows, the first two columns stay the same, the remaining three need to change on the SQL table to match the spreadsheet

The table has about a million rows and about 100 columns
I just want those specific three records in the table to match the data in the spreadsheet

I cannot update any other rows or columns.

Any way to update from the  excel or do I need to script all these 1000 + rows out?

Comment: Load the excel data into a SQL Server temporary table.

Comment: Is this a one-off, or a recurring task?

Comment: Add a column to the Excel spreadsheet to generate the individual SQL update statements you need e.g. `="UPDATE tablename SET col1 = '"&C2&"', col2 = " ... &" WHERE ... ;" etc. Then copy that column to your SQL editor and run.

Comment: Thanks, it reoccurs but data changes.  I already had done what users9601310 suggests, I was looking for a faster way.  I saw a utility call SQLSpreads but never bothered t look at the price, and I have no affiliation with them; am not endorsing or condemning etc... I guess I'll keep doing it the same way for now.. Thanks for the Replies!